# what is wrong with js syntax console.log($("h1").css("font-size"););

Tags: javascript, syntax, console.log

// why this is wrong
console.log($("h1").css("font-size"););

// console.log(); and   $("h1").css("font-size");

Comment: why by just adding this $("h1").css("font-size");    inside  consolelog (); makes whole synatx wrong

Comment: Because there shouldn't be a semicolon inside the parenthesis.

Comment: you have a semicolon in the middle of the line. Ie, instead of `););`, do `));`

Answer (score 1):

Remove the first semi colon:

```
console.log($("h1").css("font-size"));
```